# Why does Spring load messages for a different language than specified?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a simple Spring Boot application that prints a message to stdout. This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class I18nTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(I18nTestApplication.class, args);
        final Locale locale = Locale.US;

        System.out.println(ctx.getMessage("test", null, locale));
    }

}
```

The resources folder contains two message files:

**messages.properties:**

```
test=This is English
```

**messages_de.properties:**

```
test=Das ist Deutsch
```

Expected program output is: `This is English` but it is always printing `Das ist Deutsch` as output. Even if i set any locale, the program always prints the german message as output. What is going on here? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Try renaming `message.properites` to `message_en.properties` and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your name and your location in your profile page, I assume your system locale is german.

The algorithm used to find the appropriate resource bundle consists, basically in

- finding a bundle for the requested locale
- fallback to the bundle for the system locale if not found
- fallback to the default bundle if still not found

More information in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

Provide a file named messages_en.properties (even empty: keys will then be looked up in the parent bundle), and that will work as expected.

Comment: I knew the file had to be renamed to message_en.properties but this answer explains why. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed the default locale to `Locale.US` using `Locale::setDefaulLocale()` before I load the `ApplicationContext` and now I get the expected output.